# Prevent or redirect Desktop user trying to visiting mobile site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mobile

My site has a redirect code for mobile users. The problem I see happening is if a mobile user were to share my site via the link in their address bar they are sharing the mobile site. This is a problem because if the person they are sharing the link with is using a desktop computer they will be visiting the mobile site not the main site.

Is there a way to prevent desktop users from visiting the mobile site or redirect them back to the main site?

If this is not possible, showing the desktop URL instead of the mobile URL for mobile users would work fine as well. I had tried doing this with iframes but it was messing up some of the elements on my site.

IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

I was trying to use this code to mask the redirect url. The problems I ran into were my fullscreen image slider is now extremely large and blown out. And my lightbox popup no longer works as well.

As and eg: examplesite.com redirects to examplesite.com/mobile

```html
<frameset rows="100%">
  <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="http://examplesite.com/mobile" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, then maybe we can help you when you have a problem.

Comment: What are the 2 URLs and what rules have you tried?

Comment: @anubhava I have updated my question with the answer to yours.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR I will work on getting an example uploaded and will post the link!

Comment: See this link...  http://www.abeautifulsite.net/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to prevent desktop users to see mobile site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text/vnd\.wap\.wml|application/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^mobile(/.*)?$ / [L,R]
```

Comment: Just to confirm, if my mobile site is located at mobile_site I would change ^mobile to ^mobile_site in the code?

Comment: It seems to be blocking both desktop and mobile devices.  Does this go into the examplesite.com .htaccess  or the examplesite.com/mobile .htaccess